# Pandas: Group by combination of two columns in Pandas 0.23.4

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am fairly new to Python. I came across [Pandas: Group by combination of two columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51642935/pandas-group-by-combination-of-two-columns) on SO. Unfortunately, the accepted answer no longer works with pandas version `0.23.4` The objective of that post is to figure out combination of group variables, and create a dictionary for values. i.e. `group_by` should ignore the order of grouping.

Here's the accepted answer:

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter

d = pd.DataFrame([('a','b',1), ('a','c', 2), ('b','a',3), ('b','a',3)],
                 columns=['x', 'y', 'score'])

d[['x', 'y']] = d[['x', 'y']].apply(sorted, axis=1)
x = d.groupby(['x', 'y']).agg(Counter)
print(x)
```

Here, `...apply(sorted)` throws the following exception:

> raise ValueError('Must have equal len keys and value ' ValueError:
>   Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable

Here's my pandas version:

```
> pd.__version__
Out: '0.23.4'
```

Here's what I tried after reading https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html:

```
d = pd.DataFrame([('a','b',1), ('a','c', 2), ('b','a',3), ('b','a',3)],
                 columns=['x', 'y', 'score'])

d=d.sort_values(by=['x','y'],axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)
x = d.groupby(['x', 'y']).agg(Counter)
print(x)
```

Unfortunately, this also throws error:

> 1382, in _get_label_or_level_values
>       raise KeyError(key) KeyError: 'x'

**Expected output:**

```
        score           count
x   y                     
a   b   {1: 1, 3: 2}      2
    c   {2: 1}            1
```

Can someone please help me? On a side note, it will be great if you could also guide on how to compute the count of `keys()` in `score` column. I am looking for a vectorized solution.

I am using `python 3.6.7`

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is `sorted` return lists, so is necessary convert ti to `Series`:

```
d[['x', 'y']] = d[['x', 'y']].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(sorted(x)), axis=1)
```

But faster is use [`numpy.sort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html) with `DataFrame` constructor, because `apply` are loops under the hood:

```
d = pd.DataFrame([('a','b',1), ('a','c', 2), ('b','a',3), ('b','a',3)],
                 columns=['x', 'y', 'score'])

d[['x', 'y']] = pd.DataFrame(np.sort(d[['x', 'y']], axis=1), index=d.index)
```

Then seelct column for aggregation with list of aggregated functions - e.g. [`nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nunique.html) for count of number of unique values:

```
x = d.groupby(['x', 'y'])['score'].agg([Counter, 'nunique'])
print(x)
          Counter  nunique
x y                       
a b  {1: 1, 3: 2}        2
  c        {2: 1}        1
```

Or count by [`DataFrameGroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.size.html):

```
x = d.groupby(['x', 'y'])['score'].agg([Counter, 'size'])
print(x)
          Counter  size
x y                    
a b  {1: 1, 3: 2}     3
  c        {2: 1}     1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use -

```
a=d[['x','y']].values
a.sort(axis=1)
d[['x','y']] = a
x = d.groupby(['x', 'y']).agg(Counter)
print(x)
```

**Output**

```
            score
x y              
a b  {1: 1, 3: 2}
  c        {2: 1}
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding `result_type = 'broadcast'` as one of the args to `.apply()` worked.

```
>>> d = pd.DataFrame([('a','b',1), ('a','c', 2), ('b','a',3), ('b','a',3)],
             columns=['x', 'y', 'score'])
>>> d[['x', 'y']] = d[['x', 'y']].apply(sorted, axis=1, result_type='broadcast')
>>> x = d.groupby(['x', 'y']).agg(Counter)
>>> print(x)

            score
x y              
a b  {1: 1, 3: 2}
  c        {2: 1}
```

Note the difference with and without `result_type = 'broadcast'`.

```
>>> d[['x', 'y']].apply(sorted, axis=1)

0    [a, b]
1    [a, c]
2    [a, b]
3    [a, b]
dtype: object

>>> d[['x', 'y']].apply(sorted, axis=1, result_type='broadcast')

   x  y
0  a  b
1  a  c
2  a  b
3  a  b
```

As you can see, `result_type = 'broadcast'` splits (*broadcasts*) the result of `.apply()` back from a list into the respective columns, allowing the assignment to `d[['x', 'y']]`.

Comment: Good to know :-)

Comment: @Trebuchet: Thanks. This worked for me as well, but please note that `pandas` states that 'broadcast: Deprecated since version 0.23.0: This argument will be removed in a future version, replaced by result_type=’broadcast’.`